# Using Zebra LP 2844-Z over the network

Tags: printer, network-printer, label-printer

I am looking for a network-based label printer. I am looking at this [Zebra LP-2844-Z printer](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/products/printers/desktop/lp2844z.html).

1. Unfortunately, it does not come with a network interface like the lower-end LP 2824 Plus.
2. The [ZebraNet 10/100 Print Server](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/products/networking/wired/zebranet_10_100_print_server.html) is  both expensive for what it does (~$600) and only seems to support wireless networking, not wired. I prefer wired for reliability.

Questions:

1. Can I use a cheaper off-the-shelf
   print server to turn the LP-2844Z to
   a network printer.  Would I get any trouble communicating with the printer via its own programming language or via OPOS? (instead of the Windows driver)
2. Are cheaper print servers reliable? Would I be better to get
   another printer model that has it
   built in directly to avoid having
   issues due to the print server?
3. What other printer would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2- Looking at Axis print-servers [link text](http://www.axis.com/products/print_servers/index.htm)

I use them over 10 years and no problem. Low price ~ $200

Comment: and they work with Zebra printers and their proprietary programming language? (ZPL)

Comment: I don't now, but you can ask tech support Axis. If the printer has LPT interface, I think (but I cannot check it!) yes. Write to Axis.

Comment: Giving you the best answer, as this probably depends on the print server vendor.